# US Tax: Can I modify my state tax return after submitting?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, state-income-tax, itin

This is the situation I find myself in:

- I'm a student on F-1 visa, and my wife has been staying with me on a F-2 visa since the last year
- I wanted to file a married tax return, so as to get the tax exemptions for my wife as well. IRS requires a submission of an application of ITIN number for my wife, along with my tax return - which I did through the help of a Certified Acceptance Agent (CAA) who certified that my wife's passport/visa was in order, and sent the tax return along with the ITIN application to IRS. This was done on March 13, more than a month before now. I was assured by the CAA that the ITIN number would be sent by IRS way before the deadline for filing my Iowa State Tax return, which **requires** the ITIN number to be included upfront in order for me to be eligible for a tax break.

Fast forward to today - I've still not heard back from IRS, and have no clue when I will! The Iowa state taxes are due by April 30th - but if I file it without including my wife's ITIN, I'd have to pay $200 more in taxes. Hence, my question is:

1. Can I submit a tax return without my wife's ITIN number, but then later file an amendment when the ITIN number comes through, to get back the $200 in extra taxes?
2. What other options do I have - may I file it later than the deadline? I'm owing taxes to the state of Iowa either way - its the amount that is different.

Could anyone suggest an alternative, so that I don't have to pay for the dilatory administrative practices of IRS?

Comment: What's the difference? Why does ITIN reduce your tax by $200?

Comment: @littleadv - Because I get the benefit of an additional tax exemption for my spouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the responses I got from the Iowa State Tax Office after emailing them:

> Please file by paper and indicate the spouse’s ITIN has been applied for.

On asking if I had to file an amended return once the ITIN is issued by IRS?

> You will not need to file an amended return.  The department will issue your wife a temporary number on our system.  Once you receive your wife’s ITIN send us a copy of the letter and a brief note asking us to update our records as you filed your return not showing an ITIN for your spouse.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. You should file as married filing separately, and amend it later.
2. Don't file taxes late.